# How to reverse proxy all HTTP POST requests in nginx to IIS?

Tags: nginx

I run NGINX server version 1.2.6.
I would like to reverse proxy all the HTTP POST requests for a certain location to IIS.
However, all other requests other than POST should be served from the Nginx including for the same location:

```
location ~ \.aspx {
    if ($request_method = "POST") {
       #reverse proxy to the IIS
    }
    #if it's not post request
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

The problem is that when i receive POST request, the nginx gets 404.
Can someone propose a solution?

Answer (score 0):

see
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html
limit_except should help you out